# SFDX cannot deploy contentasset to an empty scratch org

Tags: deployment, salesforce, sfdc-metadata-api

I have been trying to install a package that has a contentasset metadata using sfdx force:mdapi:deploy

I have been getting this error each time.

[image]

Any Idea what might be causing this error?

Comment: That is a very good question, we faced similar issues and had to deploy content assets first. Another attempt is to use `"contentSettings": { "skipContentAssetTriggersOnDeploy": true }` on scratch org definition file, but not much of luck.

Comment: It is similar to this https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000LzTQQA0